# nohup: ignoring input - what does it mean?

Tags: nohup

I am using `nohup` command from a while like

```
nohup bash life.bash > nohup.out 2> nohup.err &
```

In the `nohup.err` file I always have a line `nohup: ignoring input`. Can you please help me figure out what it means?

Comment: If you're going to do the redirections yourself, you have almost no use for `nohup` at all; `bash life.bash >life.out 2>life.err </dev/null & disown -h "$!"` does the same using only functionality built into the shell itself.

Answer (score 24):

That’s just `nohup` telling you what it’s set up; it outputs that to its standard error, which you’ve redirected to `nohup.err`. You can avoid the message by redirecting its standard input:

```
nohup bash life.bash > nohup.out 2> nohup.err < /dev/null &
```

`nohup` checks its standard input, standard output and standard error to see which are connected to a terminal; if it finds any which are connected, it handles them as appropriate (ignoring input, redirecting output to `nohup.out`, redirecting error to standard output), and tells you what it’s done. If it doesn’t find anything it needs to disconnect, it doesn’t output anything itself.

Answer (score 9):

`nohup` is telling you exactly what it's doing, that it's ignoring input.

If you want to avoid this message, redirect *stdin* from `/dev/null` like this

```
nohup bash life.bash </dev/null >nohup.out 2>nohup.err &
```

Comment: I hope that means, its ignore all keyboard input in simple sense as its running in the background.

Answer (score 3):

```
man nohup
```

*"If  standard  input  is  a  terminal, redirect it from an unreadable file."*

Hence,

```
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
```

It is doing what it is supposed to do, notwithstanding *OPTION* entries, that's why input is being discarded.

**ALSO** It seems you are making redundant use of redirection. **nohup** already creates a nohup.out for you and, if all's working OK, *stderr* should be also redirected there.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can close the STDIN file descriptor
like this:   `<&-`

The whole line would be:

```
nohup ./script.sh >> ./out 2>&1 <&- &
```